# Apache deflate on files match condition

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-deflate

I am trying to deflate files based on the `FilesMatch` condition, I tried this but it doesn't deflate :

```
<FilesMatch \.js$>
SetOutputFilter Deflate
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /js/(.*.js) /pack.php?f=$1
</FilesMatch>
```

The rewrite rule works fine though.

Also, setting the `SetOutputFilter Deflate` outside the `FilesMatch` works as expected.

Comment: Did you try adding a `SetOutputFilter Deflate` for `/pack.php` file?

Comment: @SalmanA you are right, works now, silly me! Was setting the headers for the wrong location. Add it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When apache rewrites a rule, it re-processes certain configurations (e.g `<Directory>`, `<DirectoryMatch>`, `<Files>`, `<FilesMatch>`) to match against the "re-written" URL. This appears to be your problem.

Split your rules into two `<FilesMatch>` sections, one for `.js$` files and another for `/pack.php`. Or better, move the re-write rule outside the `<FilesMatch>` section and use a single `<Files pack.php>` section.